# Can a pg_dump or a pg_dump_all can cause timeouts in queries running in parallel?

Tags: postgresql

In my application some of the queries in a postgresql database return:

```
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] timeout expired (SQL: ^some_sql^ )
```

Whilst my queries being run I also run a backup script that uses `pg_dump` via a cron.

Can parallel pg_dump may cause query timeout if yes, under what circumstances may occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only impact that `pg_dump` can possibly have on query duration is because it also consumes the resources of the database machine, in particular I/O. That can affect the performance of concurrent queries.

Either use a lower degree of parallelization or get a more powerful machine.

Comment: So some queries can timeout because of query duration for exampole if I have long running queries or CPU intensive ones right?

Comment: Yes - a timeout is always caused by something taking too long.